# Showing tool tip in MVC when drop down item changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a select list which I use to create a drop down list, I already hooked up the jquery to get the value of the selected item when changed. This all works.

My goal is to display long text when the item changes in the drop down. This can't be stored in an option html tag because there isn't a supported attribute to accomplish this in HTML (from my understanding).

So I'd need to some how return a dictionary object from MVC to my page. I'd like to have this data on the page. I don't want to have to make a remote call every time the item changes.

My problem is I don't know how to accomplish this. In my controller I have to return a model for the list of items in the actual drop down plus additional data that needs to be displayed. So I perform a "return View(mymodel);" I am not sure how to pass this server side dictionary object to the client side so javascript can interact with it. Can someone give me some tips on how I can serialize this object with an example on how javascript can access it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand upon why you can't use JsonResult.

Comment: Hello Rich, I updated the question a bit. Hope I made myself clear now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the information in the html with hidden fields and loop through them using jquery.

For instance, in your controller you may have this:

```
    public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dict.Add("cat", "the cat is in the hat.");
        dict.Add("dog", "the dog is hiding under the fence.");
        dict.Add("mat", "the cat and the dog get hair on the mat.");

        return View("ViewPage1.cshtml", dict);

    }

}
```

And your view may have this:

```
@model Dictionary<string, string>

@{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>(Model.Keys);
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        <input id="@key" type="hidden" class="dictionary" value="@Model["key"]"   />                
    }
}
```

Then inside your item changed jquery event you could loop through the hidden fields with the class="dictionary" and use them if the id = the text for the selected item...

```
$(".dictionary").each(function(){
    if(this.attr("id") == selectedItem){
        //display logic for the hidden field's value
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.